# CSS Print: Odd Table TD Spacing Issue

Tags: html, css, printing

I have this page that looks fine but it doesn't seem to print correctly. When I use the web developer extension (for chrome of Firefox) and preview the print style sheet it seems ok. However printing it and or using the print preview give different results. There seems to be large gap between some of the table rows?

Problem page
http://wearnewzealand.com/fashion-catalogue

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any real issue here

Comment: I don’t see any large gap. But I see that content is truncated on the right, and items are split across pages vertically (photo text on a page other than the photo). Apparently, the styling has been designed for a specific page size.

Comment: Browsers handle it differently. Why don't you try adding margin, padding, borders for table in print.css